# Flutter cannot be build until build path errors are resolved

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

I can still build my Flutter project in Visual Studio & android project in Android Studio. But in Visual Studio, Flutter shows error look like the above image. Any ideas for me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean project and rebuild.

If still not solved try configuring build path.

Comment: Please show me how to config build path? in bash_profile?